# Problems with writing on serial port in Matlab

Tags: matlab, serial-port

I'm using serial cable to write commands from matlab to a camera controlled by C code.
The problem is- it sometimes works and sometimes doesn't.. and it's very frustrating.

The code I use in Matlab is:

```
Serialport=serial('COM18');
fopen(Serialport);
%Serialport.Timeout = 10000;
fwrite(Serialport,FileName); %Send File name to the camera
```

And it gets stuck in the `fwrite` function without any error. I tried to use `fprintf` instead and it still sometimes works and sometimes doesn't work.
I tried different `timeout`'s and still it doesn't work..

I have found nothing about it in the web.

Comment: what has this got to do with C++ ?

Comment: Check that the `serial.Flowcontrol` property is set to `'none'`

Comment: ...assuming that you don't need to enable software or hardware flow control.

Comment: It's set to 'none' (I guess it's the default